# Ran 'git checkout HEAD .' in the wrong directory

Tags: git

Oops, I accidentally ran 'get checkout HEAD .' in the wrong directory.
It produced the output 'Updated 2 paths from 2096756f' but I have no idea what my local changes were.
I assume that I can't find out, but I am wondering how I can protect myself in the future as this command is how I habitually discard local changes. Is there some alias I can create that for this that would protect me from such a mistake in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I accidentally ran 'get checkout HEAD .' in the wrong directory.

This is bad.

> It produced the output 'Updated 2 paths from 2096756f' but I have no idea what my local changes were.

And unless you have local backups (zfs snapshots, macOS Time Machine, etc.), they're just gone.  Git can't help you get them back: you told Git to discard them from your working tree, and it did.

> I assume that I can't find out,

If your OS keeps modification times on files, look for the two most-recently-modified files.  Those will be the two that `git checkout HEAD .` overwrote.

> I am wondering how I can protect myself in the future as this command is how I habitually discard local changes.

Change your habits.  You can't alias a built in Git command.  You *can* make a `git` alias or `git` command of your own that:

1. checks to see if you're running something "safe", or checks to see if you're using this particular command;
2. if you're running something you've deemed "safe", runs the real Git command with the same arguments, but if you're running `git checkout HEAD .`, complains and doesn't do that.

Since you're writing this command-or-alias yourself, you get to choose what goes in the "but" section of step 2.  This will (presumably) get you to change your habits.

(I try to use `git status` and then `git restore -- path/to/file` these days, so that I know just what I'm restoring; I can cut-and-paste the file name from `git status` here.)

Comment: I found the suggestion to look for recently modified files to be particularly helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some alias I can create that for this that would protect me from such a mistake in the future

No. `checkout` is dangerous and Git will not protect you from yourself.

But an excellent protection is to abandon the use of `checkout`. Instead use `switch` and `restore`. They make it much harder to make a harmful mistake.